# SAS Url is not displaying the image in browser from Azure blob Storage

Tags: c#, azure, azure-blob-storage

My intension is, i just want to access the image from azure blob when access level is private. so i have generated SAS token, it got Sas url from the api but that url when i bind to image in the front end application it is not loading the image.

SAS url for the image generated as follows:

https://Storageaccountname.blob.core.windows.net/ContainerName/azure.png?skoid=fc162e92-971d-487b-9416-42b625d6d975&sktid=6520687d-d618-4a41-944b-ed1b7d5798d4&skt=2022-08-25T18%3A12%3A20Z&ske=2022-08-25T20%3A12%3A20Z&sks=b&skv=2021-06-08&sv=2021-06-08&st=2022-08-25T18%3A12%3A28Z&se=2022-08-25T20%3A12%3A28Z&sr=b&sp=r&sig=JYGXAQVtstLzQGkAxX8eekSDd3ggViUeBDjIWoxTMRo%3D

please let us know how to load the image properly

Comment: Can you share the output you’re seeing? Also, can you trace the request in browser's network request tab (developer tools)? Are you getting 200 status code back for your request?

Answer (score 0):

•   You are encountering this error because your **container name or connection string is wrong. And the container name that is being used should be a valid DNS name conforming to a set of naming rules** as follows: -

*`a)    Container names must start with a letter or number, and can contain only letters, numbers, and the dash (-) character`*.

*`b)    Every dash (-) character must be immediately preceded and followed by a letter or number; consecutive dashes are not permitted in container names`*.

*`c)    All letters in a container name must be lowercase. Container names must be from 3 through 63 characters long`*.

Thus, as per the given SAS URL, **it doesn’t conform to the above stated rules of naming convention due to which you are encountering this error**.

For more details regarding this, kindly refer to the below link: -

***https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/naming-and-referencing-containers--blobs--and-metadata***